# Контейнеры или таблицы - таков вопрос

Tags: дизайн, веб-дизайн

Здравствуйте ХешКод, вот я читая уже не первую книгу о web-дизайне, вижу что все рекомендуют строить сайт КОНТЕЙНЕРНЫМ способом, и пишут что ТАБЛИЧНАЯ структура, уже уходит в прошлое, а на ней не стоит создавать свой сайт. Объясните пожалуйста почему не стоит делать такие сайты? Я вот уже 3 сайта сделал на табличном каркасе и  мне например очень нравится что таблицы есть даже в IE 5.5 т.е сайт лучше смотрится во всех и даже очень старый браузерах?

Answer (score 2):

Если мне не изменяет память то основная разница в том что при табличной верстке информация показывается пользователю только после загрузки всех элементов таблицы. При верстке Div-ами же информация отображается по мере загрузки конкретного блока. В итоге получаем меньшее время ожидания перед показом страницы. 
Как-то так. я уверен, прочитав еще 3-4 страницы вы найдете в любой книге пару строк о этом различии

Comment: Да я читал об этих различиях, но у меня и у других моих пользователей, таблицы грузятся очень быстро и без проблем.

Comment: До тех пор пока кто-то из сибирской деревни со старенького укропа 54к по диал-апу не захочет посмотреть ваш сайт. А такие пользователи еще есть. И их еще очень много.

ЗЫ Вот и выросло поколение

Comment: ЗЫ Вот и выросло поколение

Это в каком смысле?

Comment: В смысле что интернет настолько стал привычен и быстр что не замечаем разницы между табличной и блочной версткой, из - за больших объемов оперативки ленимся убивать дата-сеты ненужные. Фильм размером в 5Гб уже средненькое качество.
Просто полемика, ничего больше.

Comment: Т.е ничего плохого не будет если я продолжу делать сайт как таблицу, или всё-же переписывать под <div'ы>?

Comment: В любом случае сначала грузится текстовая часть, а потом картинки. Если таблица умещается на экране, то она загрузится в любом случае достаточно быстро. Когда картинки подгрузятся размеры таблицы могут быть пересчитаны, то же самое можно сказать и о div-ах.

Comment: Вы лучше таблицами - делайте таблицы в контенте, а саму верстку дивами, так логичнее. Когда сомневаетесь - совершайте логичные действия.